# 405 Not Allowed when saving product in Magento2

Tags: nginx, magento, varnish-vcl

After initial install and attempting to save the first product, the web front-end displays the following error, "The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again."

Furthermore, indexing of the product catalog fails with the same '405 Not Allowed'.

Reviewing the Magento2 debug.log the following is reported.

```
[2021-10-22 02:44:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://www.example.us/admin/catalog/product/save/t
ype/simple/store/0/set/4/key/ef0c2f7b504f823494389dbfc07b8443178f5abf9596b92b2f8511217579dc6f/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"servers"
:["[object] (Laminas\\Uri\\Uri: http://www.example.us:80/)"],"formattedTagsChunk":"((^|,)cat_p_18(,|$))"}} []
[2021-10-22 02:44:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://www.example.us/admin/catalog/product/save/t
ype/simple/store/0/set/4/key/ef0c2f7b504f823494389dbfc07b8443178f5abf9596b92b2f8511217579dc6f/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"servers"
:["[object] (Laminas\\Uri\\Uri: http://www.example.us:80/)"],"formattedTagsChunk":"((^|,)cat_p_18(,|$))"}} []
[2021-10-22 02:44:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://www.example.us/admin/catalog/product/save/t
ype/simple/store/0/set/4/key/ef0c2f7b504f823494389dbfc07b8443178f5abf9596b92b2f8511217579dc6f/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"servers"
:["[object] (Laminas\\Uri\\Uri: http://www.example.us:80/)"],"formattedTagsChunk":"((^|,)cat_p_18(,|$))"}} []
[2021-10-22 02:44:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"https://www.example.us/admin/catalog/product/save/t
ype/simple/store/0/set/4/key/ef0c2f7b504f823494389dbfc07b8443178f5abf9596b92b2f8511217579dc6f/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["
cat_p_18"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []
[2021-10-22 02:44:46] main.CRITICAL: <html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server  unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name www.example.us;
  set $MAGE_ROOT /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2;
  set $MAGE_MODE developer;
  set $MAGE_RUN_TYPE website; #or set $MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
  set $MAGE_RUN_CODE site;
  include /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/nginx.conf;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   server_name www.example.us;
   ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example-chain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example-priv.pem;
   ssl_session_timeout  1d;
   ssl_session_cache  shared:MozSSL:10m;
   ssl_session_tickets  off;
   #ssl_dhparam /path/to/dhparam.pem;
   ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
   ssl_ciphers                             ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers               off;
   # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
   add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;
   # OCSP stapling
   ssl_stapling                            on;
   ssl_stapling_verify                     on;

   set $MAGE_ROOT /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2;
   set $MAGE_MODE developer;
   set $MAGE_RUN_TYPE website; #or set $MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
   set $MAGE_RUN_CODE site;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
       proxy_set_header Host               $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port   443;
       proxy_buffer_size                   128k;
       proxy_buffers                       4 256k;
       proxy_busy_buffers_size             256k;
       fastcgi_buffer_size                 32k;
       fastcgi_buffers                     4 32k;
   }
}
```

My first thoughts are a mis-configured nginx stanza.

Also using Elasticsearch and Varnish, both test successfully. Any help would be greatly appreciated.